# Best way to check two EntitySets equality basied on one of their proprties?

Tags: c#, linq, equality, entityset

I have two Objects from the same Class, lets say it named as `Class1`, `Class1` has an `EntitySet` of `ClassChild`,
What is the best way to indicate that these Two objects have the same exact  `ClassChild's` `EntitySets` (*values and count*) based on one property of the `ClassChild` *(string one)*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SequenceEqual`-method:

```
bool equal = obj1.ClassChildren.SequenceEqual(obj2.ClassChildren)
```

That uses the default equality comparer to use a custom one see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) or this example:

```
class ClassChildComparer : IEqualityComparer<ClassChild>
{
    public bool Equals(ClassChild x, ClassChild y)
    {
        return x.Property == y.Property;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public int GetHashCode(ClassChild c)
    {
        return c.Property.GetHashCode();
    }

}

//and then:

bool equal = obj1.ClassChildren.SequenceEqual(obj2.ClassChildren, new ClassChildComparer())
```